# I want my embed colour to be set between 2 different colours

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So currently, I have a piece of code which chooses yellow to set as the colour of the embed.

`.setColor('YELLOW')`

This works fine and sets the colour of the embed to yellow. With my limited knowledge of js, I figured that adding `||` which is the logical `OR` operator, it would allow the bot to choose between either yellow or another colour. So I changed the code to this:

`.setColor('YELLOW' || 'RED')`

When I tested this code, it didn't work. It just kept the colour to yellow. I tried saving the file multiple times. I also allowed the bot to go offline and then retired it, to no avail. Could someone help me out, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OR (`||`) operator always returns the [first truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), `YELLOW` in your case.

If you only want to choose between those two, you can put them in an array and use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to generate a random number. If this number is less than `0.5`, you can choose the first one, if it's larger, choose the second one:

```js
console.log(['YELLOW', 'RED'][Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1])
console.log(['YELLOW', 'RED'][Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1])
console.log(['YELLOW', 'RED'][Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1])
```

You can update your code like this:

```js
.setColor(['YELLOW', 'RED'][Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1])
```